# Como criar sistema de tag similar ao Blogger?

Tags: php, mysql, nuvem-de-tags

Senhores,

Estou tentando adicionar ao meu CMS (em PHP/MySQL) um sistema de Tags similar ao do Blogger.

Na página de cadastro da notícia, gostaria que o administrador adicionasse no campo "tags", informações separadas por vírgulas.

Dessa forma, ao cadastrar as informações, todas as notícias ficariam "vinculadas" (relacionadas) às notícias classificadas com a mesma "tag" e seria criada uma página individual para a tag, relacionando todas as notícias com a mesma classificação.

Comment: Certo, mas o que você já te feito para que possamos ajudar?

Comment: Tenho todo o sistema de cadastro de notícias pronto.
Mas pensei em implementar essa funcionalidade.

Andei lendo a respeito de relacionamento entre banco de dados:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063628/php-mysql-tagging-system-logic?rq=1

Comment: Coloque se puder para ficar mais fácil adaptar qualque resposta

Comment: Existem muitas maneiras de se fazer isso e acredito que sua pergunta atual é [muito ampla](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Recomendo que você vá fazendo uma pergunta específica de cada vez, focando em cada problema que você encontrar enquanto constrói o sistema. Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar detalhes.

Comment: Explicando melhor, aparentemente seu problema atual é a estrutura do BD, então sugiro focalizar a pergunta em qual parte do relacionamento não entende. Como está construindo seu banco, qual código está testando...